# N - more comments misalignment in Stack Exchange app

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

There is misalignment in showing the "*N - more comments*" in Stack Exchange app.  A little hard to describe so I have added the screenshots.

[image]

Not a big deal but wanted to let you know.

**Updates:**
Just now realized that this issue could be due to screen resolution *(I'm using Samsung Galaxy s Duos s7562)*

Comment: Yep, this is a known issue on small-width devices.

Comment: @AndrewT. Would be nice to check the dateTime of my question and your mapped duplicate question.  I don't mind closing the question; just FYI.