# The "x more comments" phrase is cut off

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app

In the Android app, the "x more comments" phrase is cut off by the button next to it, "Add a comment":

[image]

It looks like the rest of the phrase is underneath the button and there is some space to the left of the phrase. Can we shift the "x more comments" phrase more to the left so it doesn't get cut off by the "Add a comment" button? At the very least, please allow the phrase to not be cut off by the "Add a comment" button somehow.

Comment: As [Kasra commented on other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221364/n-more-comments-misalignment-in-stack-exchange-app#comment719659_221364), "*Yep, this is a known issue on small-width devices.*" Good proposal, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

I observed this on a Nexus 5 which has a slightly larger screen than my iPhone 6. I'm dropping the font size by 1sp and the button width by 40dp.  The preview suggests this should work on anything bigger than a Nexus One.